# Get collection ID's that are inside a document in Google Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is a document "TestAccount" which holds 2 collections. Is there a way to know the collection names when I query for the "TestAccount" document?

[image]

This will not print out the collection names:

```
db.collection("users").document("TestAccount").getDocument { (allDocs, allDocsErrors) in
        guard let _allDocs = allDocs,
            allDocs?.exists ?? false,
            allDocsErrors == nil else {
                print("early exit \(allDocs?.exists)") //always fires
                return
        }
```

Comment: check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document

Answer (score 0):

checkout this code , I remove the `allDocs?.exists ?? false,allDocsErrors == nil` from `guard` condition list , this should work fine

```
db.collection("users").document("TestAccount").getDocument 
{ 
    (documentSnapshot, error) in

    guard let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot else { 
        print("early exit \(documentSnapshot?.exists)");
        return
    }

    let children = documentSnapshot.data();
    for (id , value) in children 
    {
        print(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try listCollections() on the document, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document

However, it's not recommend to build into your app.